# how to access json data through javascript

Tags: json

I am developing JMAKI widgets,my task is to display the json data in a html page through javascript.

What's the best way to access the json data through javascript?

Answer (score 2):

if you have the json object already just access as you would with a normal object:

```
// Creating the JSON object from string
var obj = JSON.parse('{"attr1": 10, "attr2": "Some value"}');

// You can access it like this
var a = obj.attr1;
var b = obj.attr2;

console.log(a, b); // Will print 10, "Some value"
```

For me that is the best way to access a JSON object (not the only one) it feels more natural for me.

Answer (score 0):

use `eval(json-object)`, if you trust the source, or you can use the json parser [here](http://www.json.org/json_parse.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
object = eval("(" + json_string + ")")
```

or

```
object = JSON.parse(json_string)`
```